# Why doesn't source control check in my CocoaPods?

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I have a few Cocoapods installed for my project. For one particular pod, KVNProgress, Xcode doesn't commit it to GitHub. Each time I check my project out I get 'can't find KVNProgress.h' blah blah...

So I run 'pod update' from terminal and immediately all is fixed. 
After running 'pod update', I check my project navigator and there are no 'A' or 'M' or anything else for that matter indicated a new or modified file. Therefor nothing to commit.

Any ideas how to fix this so I don't have to update the pods each time I check out the project?

Comment: Maybe you have added the "Pods" directory to your .gitignore? Or you are using a gitignore you got from the web, some of them ignore the CocoaPods source files.

Comment: I'm not using .gitignore at all actually.

Comment: Use Terminal to run `git status --ignored` in the Project directory and see if it shows any Pods files. Maybe it's an Xcode problem and not a git problem. (the `--ignored` will show ignored files as well, just in case)

Comment: How About that! Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 CorpBoard.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/____.xcuserdatad/
 Pods/Headers/Build/KVNProgress/
 Pods/Headers/Public/KVNProgress/
 Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/____.xcuserdatad/

Comment: Don't know how that happened but I never thought to check that. If you'll submit that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the Terminal to figure out if it's an Xcode problem or a git problem.

Run `git status --ignored` in the project directory. If the `Pods` directory is shown in the *Ignored files* section you have to remove Pods from your `.gitignore` file.

If the files appear in the *untracked files* section Xcode messed up the git status.
You can use `git add .` to add all untracked files.

---

As a side note, I would recommend to use a dedicated git client like [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com), [GitHub Mac](https://mac.github.com), or [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com) instead of Xcode. Xcodes git implementation is not the best (feature wise) and it's a bit buggy.

Comment: Thanks. I do use GitHub Mac, though it is no longer supported.